# React errors showing in console but not window

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I work with a CRA app, and most React Apps, an error in the code will cause the browser to show an error screen instead of the application.

The legacy code I'm working on doesn't do this. An error that basically crashes the app just shows a blank screen (black screen, which I imagine is our background color), and you only know what's going on by opening the dev console for the browser.

The project was made with CRA, but quite a while ago. It does not include `react-scripts` anywhere.

How do I set this back to "normal" so that the errors will show in the browser window itself?

This is my current webpack config

```js
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const ip = require('my-local-ip');
const colors = require('colors');
const process = require('process');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const states = require('./util/state-spoof');
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const PlayerIdPlugin = require('./plugins/PlayerIdPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin');

const envPort = process.env.PORT;
const port = envPort ? envPort : 3000;

const spoof = states[process.env.SPOOF || 'NH'];

const forcedProdAPI = process.env.FORCE_PROD_API || false;

const platform = os.platform().toLowerCase();

const isLinux = platform === 'linux';
const isWindows = platform === 'win32' || platform === 'win64';
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const sessionKey = process.env.SESSION_KEY || '';

const linter = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  use: [
    {
      options: {
        formatter: eslintFormatter,
        eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

      },
      loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
    },
  ],
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
};

const imgLoad = {
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
  loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
  options: {
    limit: 10000,
    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
  },
};

const jsLoad = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
  loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
  options: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
  },
  exclude: /(node_modules)/,
};

const tsLoad = {
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: 'ts-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
};

const sassLoad = {
  test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    mode.includes('dev') ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
    },
  ],
};

const fileLoad = {
  exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
  loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
  options: {
    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
  },
};

module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  stats: 'errors-only',
  entry: './src/browser/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'public'),
    filename: 'static/scripts/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      linter,
      { oneOf: [imgLoad, jsLoad, tsLoad, sassLoad, fileLoad] },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new PlayerIdPlugin({
      output: path.resolve(
        __dirname, '..', 'src', 'browser', 'services', 'PlayerIDHelper.js'
      ),
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
      'process.env.FORCE_PROD_API': JSON.stringify(forcedProdAPI),
      'process.env.SESSION_KEY': JSON.stringify(sessionKey),
      'process.env.NERF_THIRD_PARTY': 'false',
      'process.env.BROWSER': 'true',
      'process.env.SPOOF': JSON.stringify(spoof),
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'static/styles/main.css',
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: port,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    quiet: true,
    compress: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    before: () => {
      console.log(
        colors.bold.white(
          `Server currently listening :\n`
        ) +
        colors.reset.yellow(
          `\nMachine access: http://localhost:${port}\n`
        ) +
        colors.reset.yellow(
          `Network access: http://${ip()}:${port}`
        )
      );

      if (!isLinux && !isWindows) {
        childProcess.execSync('ps cax | grep "Google Chrome"');
        childProcess.execSync(
          `osascript chrome.applescript "${encodeURI(
            `http://localhost:${port}`
          )}"`,
          {
            cwd: path.resolve(__dirname),
            stdio: 'ignore',
          }
        );
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: There's not much information to go on - that legacy code is presumably still React, but is it using `react-scripts`, some other equivalent, a custom toolchain, ...? I believe CRA uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-overlay via https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils to provide that functionality, how (and whether) you can apply it will likely depend entirely on your context.

Comment: If your react is v. 16 or higher: [use an error boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Comment: @jonrsharpe not much to go on indeed. I'll add my webpack config.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `webpackHotDevClient` in `react-dev-utils` seems to be at least the first big step toward the answer. Feel free to post that as a more detailed answer and I'm happy to mark it.